# How to tell if a List contains a Map key

Tags: java, dictionary, linked-list

I am trying to write a while loop that will continue to iterate until the nodes list does not have a certain key in a it's map.  My code looks like this:

```
List<Map<Integer, Integer>> nodes = new LinkedList<Map<Integer, Integer>>();
List<Integer> parent = new LinkedList<Integer>();
.
.
.
while (parent != null) {
        int vertex = parent.remove(0);
        while(//The problem )
    }
}
```

I will be pulling the integer from parent and placing  it into vertex and will be using vertex to find the key in the nodes.  What would the call look like to find the integer in nodes?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure if that's what you want but it might.

```
    List<Map<Integer, Integer>> nodes = new LinkedList<Map<Integer, Integer>>();
    LinkedList<Integer> parent = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    // ^ or Queue to use .poll() which removes the first item

    Integer parentItem;
    while ((parentItem = parent.poll()) != null) {
        // check if that item is somewhere in the maps
        boolean inMaps = false;
        for(Map<Integer, Integer> map : nodes) {
            if (map.containsKey(parentItem)) {
                inMaps = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        // if it is not do something special, maybe "return" or "break;"
        if (!inMaps) {
            // do something.
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
for(int vertex: parent) {
   for(Map<Integer, Integer) entry : nodes) {
      if(entry.contains(vertex) {
         //the map entry has the key, write your logic and return
         return entry
      }
   }
}
```